# Regarding setting up the target tensor shape for sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to experiment with a multi-layer encoder-decoder type of network. The screenshot of the last several layers of network architecture is as follows.  This is how I setup model compiling and training process.

```
optimizer = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=False)
    autoencoder.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(imgs_train, imgs_mask_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

`imgs_train` and `imgs_mask_train` are of shape `(2000, 1, 128, 128)`. `imgs_train` represent the raw image and `imgs_mask_train` represents the mask image. I am trying to solve a semantic segmentation problem. However, running the program generates the following error message, (I only keep the main related part).

```
tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow.StatusNotOK: Invalid argument: logits first dimension must match labels size.  logits shape=[4096,128] labels shape=[524288]                                                                                                      
         [[Node: SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_364, Cast_158)]]
```

It seems to me that the loss function of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` causes the problem for the current (imgs_train, imgs_mask_train) shape setting. The Keras API does not include the detail about how to setup the target tensor. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to figure the same problem and as far as I can tell it takes a sparse representation of the target category. That means integers as the target label instead of the one-hot encoded binary class matrix.

Concerning your problem, do you have categories in your masking or do you just have information about the outline of an object? With outline information it becomes a pixel wise binary loss instead of a categorical one. If you have categories, the output of your decoder should have dimensionality (None, number_of_classes, 128, 128). On that you should be able to use a sparse target mask but I haven't tried this myself...
Hope that helps